# Integrating in Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Calculate the following integral in the following region:

$$Q_r=\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: -r \le x,y\leq r\rbrace$$

$$\iint_{Q_r} e^{-x^2-y^2} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$

---

Since the region where the integration occurs is infinite, I first figured out that it would be easier to convert the cartesian coordinates to polar. I transformed the function and put the central point from which I want to integrate in the origin

So I would have to integrate $f(x,y)=e^{-(x-r)^2-(y+r)^2}$ ,with $x\ge 0$ and $y \le 0$ thus the angle $\theta$ will vary between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0$

How I proceed from here to get the volume of the region in terms of $r$?

Comment: Do you mean $-r\le x\le r $ and $ -r\le y \le y$.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I put in polar coordinates to avoid the problem of integrating $e^{-x^2-y^2}$ because they are not integrable in the "regular functions"

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah It's an infinite region in the $\mathbb{R}^2$, they meant what I put above.

Comment: $-r\le x,y\le r$ is not clear mathematically .

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: it sort if is: $(x,y)\in[-r,r]\times[-r,r]$. The problem with that region is that it does not transform nicely through polar coordinates.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah It's a "$\wedge$"  instead ",". I coppied from a exercise, but I assumed it was a $\wedge$ from context. The region is infinite

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira: what are you trying to achieve? the region of integration, being a square, does not have a nice representation in terms of polar coordinates, like say, the disk or radius $r$ would.

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira In this case, polar coordinates are not pratical.

Comment: [Error Functions and more...](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2).

Comment: @OliverDiaz I get that, but since the "region tends to infinite" the two integrations would be the same

Comment: Using the obvious symmetry: $-y\in(-\infty,r]\Leftrightarrow y\in[-r,\infty)$, we get
$$I=\int_{x=-r}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\cdot\int_{y=-r}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}\,dy=\left(\int_{x=-r}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)^2.$$ Therefore $I$ cannot be written in terms of elementary functions because then the error function would be the square root of one such. That is, an elementary function, which it isn't.

Comment: @JoséPedroFerreira: That is true, but the OP, although mentions infinity, it does not make it clear that you want to compute the value of $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $O = (0,0), A = (1,0), B = (1,1), C = (0,1)$, then the region $Q_r$ is made up of $4$ such congruent squares. Thus you only need to integrate over one of them and multiply the result by $4$ to obtain the main result. Thus call the square $\square OABC$ $S_r$, then $S_r$ again is made up of a quarter of a circle centered at the origin that we call $T_r$, and a tiny wedge between this quarter circle and the square. Call this wedge $W_r$, then $S_r = T_r \cup W_r\implies \int \int_{Q_r}= 4\int \int_{S_r}= 4\int \int_{T_r\cup W_r} = 4\left(\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \displaystyle \int_{0}^{r} \delta e^{-\delta^2} d\delta d\theta+\displaystyle \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{r}^{\frac{r}{\cos \theta}}\delta e^{-\delta^2}d\delta d\theta+ \displaystyle \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \displaystyle \int_{r}^{\frac{r}{\sin \theta}}\delta e^{-\delta^2} d\delta d\theta\right)$. You can work it out to simplify it.

Comment: It seems to me that the region is the unbounded quarter plane $[-r,\infty)\times(-\infty,r]$. Check out the comments. The comma does not seek to convey that the same lower and upper bounds would apply to both $x$ and $y$. Rather it is one inequality giving a lower bound to $x$ and another giving an upper bound to $y$. Admittedly it is ambiguos because similar notation is often used to bound both coordinates to the same interval.

Comment: May be it isn't homework? :-)